# OpenVPN - how to have client web servers available on server's entire local network

Tags: openvpn

Currently my OpenVPN client successfully connects to my OpenVPN Ubuntu server, and from my server's browser is accessible as 10.1.0.25.
How to make it so that the client can be accessed on every computer in the server's local network under the IP 10.1.0.25?

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable IP forwarding on my Ubuntu server.
This is done with `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, and the result can be checked by `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`